# How to fix the jquery url.indexOf function not defined at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a web application application in MVC using jQuery.

Now I am getting this error again and again. I don't know what I am missing right now.

Can anyone guide me about this?

It throws this error message in browsers' console:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: url.indexOf is not a function TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
>
> at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (http://localhost:5713/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:9793:13)
>   at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:5713/Theme/js/main.js:27:12)
>   at mightThrow (http://localhost:5713/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:3570:29)
>   at process (http://localhost:5713/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:3638:12) undefined jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3846
>   jquery-3.1.1.js:3855 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
>   at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery-3.1.1.js:9793)
>   at HTMLDocument. (main.js:27)
>   at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
>   at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With `Jquery 3.x` there were some breaking changes in the Library

[Jquery Breaking Changes](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

Jquery Removed the `load`,`unload` and `error` event listeners completely, although they were deprecated long back in `Jquery 1.8`.

use `.on` to register your event.

Comment: thank you Shehkar. but how should i use then if i want to use these Window.load function.

$(window).load(function(){'use strict';
  var $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
  var $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
  $portfolio.isotope({
   itemSelector : '.portfolio-item',
   layoutMode : 'fitRows'
  });
  
  $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
   $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
   $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
   return false;
  });
 });

Comment: `$(window).on('load',function(){  // your code here  });`